# How to fix 'unable to connect to chromedriver'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, bitbucket-pipelines

I create one capybara test. It works on local machine but at bitbucket pipeline not.

I set port

```
Capybara.server_port = 9516
```

but then the capybara test tries to connect to 9516.

```
1) Visit back office The admin can sign in Failure/Error:
visit(back_office_path) Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9516
./spec/features/home_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'capybara', '~> 3.14.0'
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 3.14.1'
gem 'webdrivers', '~> 3.0'
```

spec_helper.rb

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'selenium/webdriver'
require 'webdrivers'

Capybara.register_driver(:headless_chrome) do |app|
  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
    chromeOptions: { args: %w[headless disable-gpu] }
  )

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app,
    browser: :chrome,
    desired_capabilities: capabilities
  )
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :headless_chrome
Webdrivers::Chromedriver.required_version = '2.46'
```

Do you have some idea about how to solve it?

Comment: how are you installinng chromedriver on the machine? Are you sure it's in the PATH?

Comment: Setting `Capybara.server_port` sets the port Capybara runs the application under test on - it has absolutely nothing to do with chromedriver. What output are you getting when you don't set the `server_port`. What version of Chrome are you using, and why are you locking chromedriver at 2.46?

Comment: @maxpleaner I use gem `webdrivers` that install chromedriver

Comment: @ThomasWalpole When I don't set port for capybara then I received message:
`unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9516`. Webdriver use version '2.46'